# should i delete .AndroidStudio1.2 folder now

Tags: android, android-studio

I see these folders in my username file and wonder if i could delete two of them:

```
.AndroidStudio1.2 

.AndroidStudio1.3 

.AndroidStudioPreview1.3
```

The `StudioPreviewpreview1.3` takes `1.3 G` of storage and the `Studio1.2` takes `773 MB` of storage. I'd like to know if any of these folders do anything now. I'm getting messages there's an even newer version available.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**YES, you can delete them!** They are old config files. When you install the new version it asks you if you want to import old config or not. No matter the answer these folders remain. Don't delete the .android folder since that contains the AVDs.

To make sure that Android Studio is not using this you can check the last modified date on some of the files and directories.